# Having an issue with UPDATING SQL Database via PHP Table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html-table

Trying to Update the MySQL Tables but nothing is being updated, I'm sure I'm just not seeing the tiny issue, would love some help. Thanks

So its a trade block for a hockey pool, if you want the player on the trade block then you just check the CHECKBOX in the form and submit and it should change the value in the database to value of "1".

FORM:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";

echo "<tr><th>NAME</th> <th>POS</th> <th>BLOCK</th></tr>";

$counter = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "<tr><td>"; 

echo "{$row['f_name']}" . " " . "{$row['l_name']}";

echo "</td><td><input name='pl_id[$counter]' type='hidden' value='{$row['pl_id']}'>";

echo "{$row['pos']}";

echo "</td><td><input name='pos[$counter]' type='hidden' value='{$row['pos']}'>";                                   


    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='block[$counter]' size='1' value='1'";

    if($row['block'] == '1')
    {
        echo "checked='checked'";
    }

    echo "></td></tr>";                 

$counter++;

} 
echo "</table>";
```

SUBMIT PHP PAGE:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mbbcom1_fantrax") or die(mysql_error());

$i = 1;
while ($i < 26) {

$block = $_POST['block'][$i];
$pl_id = $_POST['pl_id'][$i];

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE 'players'
                     SET  `block` = '$block' 
                     WHERE `players`.`pl_id` = '$pl_id'");                  
mysql_query($query); 

$i++; }

echo mysql_close();
```

Comment: Do `echo mysql_error();` before `mysql_close();` so we can see what error MySQL is giving.

Comment: You put your database username/password into the question. I've edited it out, but you should change them.

Comment: may be you should remove the quotes wrapping the table name(players) in the last update statement and use grave accent instead. just guessing because i remember facing the same trouble

Comment: little tip: optimize your while loop. Instead of using while and for you can do enough by only using while:

`while ($i < $formSize && $i < 26){

   YOUR STATEMENTS

   $i++;
}`

Comment: Ok so I updated it with all the suggestions but still no luck, I modified the code here as well. Cant believe how fast you guys are thought. Thank you so much

Comment: Here is the page LIVE: maybe that can help you guys help me ;) http://www.mbb87.com/fantrax/myblock.php?user=92&inblock=1

Answer (score 2):

Remove comma before WHERE

mysql_query("UPDATE 'players'
                     SET  `block` = '$block'
                     WHERE `players`.`pl_id` = '$pl_id'");

Answer (score 0):

You have a } to less, so the PHP code doesn't run.

You do a while loop and a foreach loop, but you are only closing the for loop.

And of course you don't need a , before the `WHERE` statement